# Check if an array element/item is undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, math

How do I add to `z` only if `y` exists **without** adding a zero instead?

```
var x=[-1,2,44,6];

var y=[33,2,1];      //a shorter array where y[3] does not exist

var z=[];

var i=x.length;

while(i--){

    z[i]=x[i]+y[i];

    }
```

When I know that all the `x`'s exist but i do not know if there is a `y` for each `x`.

Also the problem may include more arrays of varying undetermined sizes (not just x and y, say t, u, v, w named arrays that may or may not have same lengths)

How would I loop through adding all arrays together without changing the loop, creating NaN or adding any zeros?

Can this be done inline?

Comment: `if (x.length == y.length)` ?

Comment: What does "`without changing the loop`" mean? You won't modify your code?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works best

```
var y=[];
var x=[1];
var z=(x[0]+(y[0]?y[0]:null)||undefined);
```

`y` has no existing values. `x` has a value we know exists. I can safely add `x` to `z` and safely add null to `z` if `y` does not exist. For whatever reason if everything were to go null then I end up with `z` undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You just need a `if` condition to check if the lengths of the array are equal.

```
if(x.length == y.length) {
  var i = x.length;
  while(i--)
    z[i]=x[i]+y[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while (i--) {
    z[i] = ((i > y.length - 1)? x[i] : x[i] + y[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var x=[-1,2,44,6];

var y=[33,2,1];      //a shorter array where y[3] does not exist

var z=[];

var i=Math.max(y.length, x.length);

while(i--){
    if (typeof y[i] !== 'undefined'  && x[i] !== 'undefined')  {
       z[i]=x[i]+y[i];
    }
}
```